# "Find" Permission Denied

Tags: permissions, xorg

I am a new user of Ubuntu and I was trying to find my `xorg.conf`. I used

```
find / -name xorg.conf
```

but it says "permission denied" like in this image. What can I do to get the permission?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFIZ8.jpg

Answer (score 3):

Use sudo:

```
sudo find / -name xorg.conf
```

sudo allows a permitted user to execute a command as the superuser or another user.

For more info:

```
man sudo
```

(you can quit with <kbd>Q</kbd>)

Answer (score 2):

You are getting all those "permission denied" messages because the directories are not readable by you and you are not running as root. xorg.conf would be in a readable/traversable directory anyway (/etc/X11), so if you didn't find it, it doesn't exist (but read on). If you don't want to see all the permission denied messages, just redirect stderr to /dev/null (2>/dev/null)

Modern Xorg servers do not really need an xorg.conf. If you must have one, run Xorg -configure (relevant man pages: Xorg(1) and xorg.conf(5)).

Comment: So, if i want to change my screen resolution to 1280x1024 how should I do?

Comment: @Adrian Please make a new question to get an answer to. New questions in a comment are confusing. ;c)

Answer (score 1):

> You are getting all those "permission denied" messages because the
> directories are not readable

Try:

```
sudo find -perm -a+r / -name xorg.conf
```

**-perm -a+r** means that the current user (which is root once sudo is taken), its group and others must all have read permission

Answer (score 0):

Direct Answer: Use `sudo` to run with administrative privileges.  More precisely, as described in the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man8/sudo.8.html): "sudo allows a permitted user to execute a command as the superuser or another user, as specified by the security policy."

```
sudo find / -name xorg.conf
```

Best Answer: Use `locate` instead.

```
locate xorg.conf
```

Cool Answer: add `2>/dev/null` at the end to discard error/warning messages.  `-iname` is cool because it makes the search case insensitive.

```
find / -iname xorg.conf 2>/dev/null
```

- Credit for the `2>/dev/null` part: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/231626/145311
- Basic Find command reference: http://www.binarytides.com/linux-find-command-examples/